# Dev Tools auto-complete doesn't work on chrome 35, ubuntu 14.04

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

After update to chrome 35, autocomplete in dev tools doesn't work. Is it only my issue?

Checked windows and mac, all works..

Answer (score 8):

I've got some similar problems, but just on Styles panel on Elements tab. Here, I've opened an issue just to this case:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=376763&thanks=376763&ts=1400852713

I know it's not a solution, but it's the best we can do. We have to wait for someone at google (or that's involved with chromium project) fix it, and then release a new version patching it.

An alternative is using Chromium from ubuntu Software Center for now (it's still at version 34, so the autocomplete works): https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/chromium-browser/

**UPDATE**

This bug has been fixed on version 36

Comment: Another alternative is to install Chrome Beta. It works SxS and don't have the autocomplete issue.

Answer (score 2):

The issue has been fixed in the beta version.

(works in the current version: 36.0.1985.49 beta)

Can be download from http://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/beta.html

Comment: I'm using 36.0.1985.103 beta and it does not work. It shows completions in grey, but no key to pick the completion works (tab, end, or arrow keys all have no effect). It is extremely annoying. Update: using the mouse to pick a completion from the menu does work.

Answer (score 1):

**edit**: 
Considering the initial message, I assumed the problem was to pop the autocomplete box in the source files search as i enter in this issue. If the problem ain't relative to this, sorry.

In the last version the auto-completion menu in dev tools doesn't appears automatically anymore, u need to press cmd+P or cmd+O (mac) to open it.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem. It's really annoying.

Besides, on the Elements tab, when you double click the attribute of an arbitrary tag, the attribute is automatically emptied, which, i think, is not really expected.

Hope these issues get solved as quickly as possible.